# Using installer variables in scan directory for install4j

Tags: classpath, install4j

The legacy app i'm working on is downloading classes on windows to the users AppData:

${installer:sys.userHome}/AppData/Local/TheOrg/${installer:productName}/Lib

'productName' is a installer variable that is configurable as a step in the installer

This is given as an argument to the main class by the installer and at that point
${installer:sys.userHome} and ${installer:productName} resolves correctly

However when I use the same location (${installer:sys.userHome}/AppData/Local/TheOrg/${installer:productName}/Lib) as a Class Path as value of an 'Scan Directory" entry something seems off. If I hard code this to
C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/TheOrg/MyApp/Lib everything works fine.

What is the difference between 'Directory' and 'Scan Directory', and are there any reasons why the Classpath isn't picked up correcly when I'm using variables?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use installer variables in the class path entries of a launcher. You can see that in the variable selector which does not offer installer variables.

[image]

The technical reason is that the class path is constructed by the native launcher which does not have access to installer variables because they are read and instantiated by the Java part of the installer.

On Windows, you can use the environment variable `${LOCALAPPDATA}` in class path entries to refer to the local app data directory.

Btw, use `${installer:sys.localAppdataDir}` instead of `${installer:sys.userHome}/AppData/Local`, the location of that directory might not be in the user home directory.